# How to click on row element by text instead of xpath using selenium 2 robotframework

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
    <div class="dataTables_scrollHead ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
    <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="position: relative; overflow: auto; width: 100%;">
       <table id="DataTables_Table_4" class="dataTable no-footer" role="grid" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_4_info" style="width: 100%;">
           <thead>
           <tbody>
               <tr class="odd" role="row">
               <tr class="even" role="row">
                   <td class="center-col multiRowSelect sorting_1">
                   <td>GROUP4</td>
                   <td class=" center-col">Enterprise Open</td>
                   <td class=" center-col">0</td>
               </tr>
           </tbody>
       </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I think you should clarify your question a bit with examples of what you have tried so far, and what output you are expecting. See [how to ask a question.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello Maruthi, please clarify your question! What do you mean with text?

Answer (score 1):

Are you absolutely sure you don't like xpath for that? It is awfully powerful and can in fact very well be used to find by text:

```
Click Element    xpath=//*[contains(text(),"GROUP")]/parent::tr
```